# How do I read '% Time in GC' in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management

I try to read the memory performance counter '% Time in GC' by

```
 Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
 PerformanceCounter gcTimeCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "% Time in GC");
```

but that raises an exception of type InvalidOperation. How can I read this parameter ?

Comment: It *seems wrong*? In what way does it seem wrong?

Comment: raises an InvalidOperation exception

Comment: Wrong category, use ".net clr memory"

Comment: @AlexK.thanks. You may convert it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That counter is contained within the *.NET CLR Memory* category so:

```
PerformanceCounter gcTimeCounter = 
   new PerformanceCounter(".NET CLR Memory", "% Time in GC");
```